# InputStream.available() is returning 0 or No file size

Tags: file-io, java-me

Please consider the following j2me code segment:

```
1. FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///root1/photos/2.png");
2. InputStream is = fc.openInputStream();
3. System.out.println(is.available());
4. byte[] fileBytes = new byte[is.available()];
5. int sizef = is.read(fileBytes);
6. System.out.println("filesize:"+sizef);
```

In this case line 3 & 6 both outputs 0 as file size. But when I put `is.read(anyByteArray)` this line after line 2 it shows the proper file size. Why is this happening? I think I don't understand these class very well. Any pointer for better understanding?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about j2me, but the Java6 javadoc for InputStream.available() says this:

> Note that while some implementations
>   of InputStream will return the total
>   number of bytes in the stream, many
>   will not. It is never correct to use
>   the return value of this method to
>   allocate a buffer intended to hold all
>   data in this stream.

Comment: Then how shall I know how much bytes is in my input stream?